# Saving values in a session

Tags: php, python, session, web

I need your help.

Through the URL I get Data for the position and that value is getting passed to a python script.

The first time everything is fine, they value 200 comes in and the stepper make 200 steps and reaches the defined position. The next time, another value is requested like 100 or maybe -100 (just for example), through the steps a defined position should be reached.

The Problem is if my stepper is on 200 steps and should reach position -100 he actually needs -300 steps but through the button click in the index.php the value -100 is getting passed.

I tried to solve this problem with a session to overwrite the actual position and get the the "real" value via subtracting or adding up both values                    but it doesn't work out for me...

Have you got any ideas how can i solve it ?

```
session_start();

$newvalue = ($_GET["value"]);


$_SESSION['test'] = $oldvalue + $newvalue ;

echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

The problem is I don't know how to save the `oldvalue` when the page gets refreshed and the new value is coming in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
session_start();
$valueThatYouFetch = $_GET["value"]; // Fetch your value

if (isset($_SESSION['test'])) { // If session exist
  $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test'] + $valueThatYouFetch; // add old value to new one
} else { // if session does not exist
  $_SESSION['test'] = $valueThatYouFetch; // Create session and add the value to session
}

echo isset($_SESSION['test']) ? $_SESSION['test'] : 'session was not created';
```